# How to install Adobe Master Collection CS6 in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: software-installation

I have Dell Inspiron 1545 Laptop with Windows 7 installed on it.Also I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 on a separate drive.I want to install Adobe Master Collection CS6 on Ubuntu 12.10.I tried using wine but what wine does is,it just installs the software & doesn't allow me to use it.While I click on any Adobe product say Adobe Photoshop & hit enter to run it it pops out an error message.

How should I tackle this?Is there any other software apart from virtual Machine Ware or Wine to install & successfully run Adobe Master Collection CS6 in Ubuntu 12.10?

Comment: Rule #1: If you have an error message and you want others to help you, post the error message, even if it makes no sense to you. Rule #2: Google your error messages to solve your problems yourself, that's what most of the others do.

Comment: Rule #3: look it up on Wine's Appdb before coming here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that Wine, and VM might be the way to run Adobe Master Collection CS6 in Ubuntu.

My recomendation would be to use VM, because it will run the application better that Wine.  Wine is still a compatibility layer that may have some problems, and incompatibility.

One other thing you can try is [Playonlinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/), although it may have the same results as Wine.  You may look at the Wine [AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25607), where you can get information on application compatibility with Wine.

You may also look at [Creative suite for Linux](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/12/creative-suite-for-linux-an-update/).

Answer (score -1):

Wine is an excellent way to run Windows programs on Linux although it still cannot run everything 100%, although older versions of Photoshot and such have been known to work properly...

What you could try is VirtualBox which is available in the Software Centre and allows you to install Windows inside a window and runs a perfect Windows environment from which to install and launch your Windows applications...

Be warned that since this is an emulation of Windows it will run slower, as will any running applications, but it is a good alternative to booting to and from Linux/Win just to run specific software and the Guest Additions package for VirtualBox always manages to speed things up like graphics...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Though the question is slightly unclear, the original poster is almost certainly asking about how to install CS6 *without* Wine or virtualization. Since this question is likely [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/185080), **I do believe this is a genuine answer**. However, this would be even better if you were to expand it a bit to directly address the question's last paragraph. If you have any insight into why the OP may not have been able to run the installed software with Wine, that might help too. (You can edit your posts, if you so choose.)